# Google Analytics - Clear value of GA cookies when user is logged out

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, session-cookies

Using javascript , how do I clear/ remove the values of Google Analytics cookies of _gid and _ga ?

[GA cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3231.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for the answer

```
document.cookie = '_ga=; path=/; domain='+ domainValue + '; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString();
document.cookie = '_gid=; path=/; domain='+ domainValue + '; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString();
```